# MS Dynamics Query audit in C# returning EntityReference instead of name

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I know that in order to request audit details for a specific record, I need to use a call like this:

```
var changedBy = auditDetailsResponse.AudtiDetail.AuditRecord.Attributes["userid"];
```

But in the console, I'm getting returns like this:

```
Changed By: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference
```

Trying this:

```
var changedBy = (EntityReference)auditDetailsResponse.AudtiDetail.AuditRecord.Attributes["userid"];
```

Yields the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing like this.

```
var changedById = ((EntityReference)auditDetailsResponse.AudtiDetail.AuditRecord.Attributes["userid"]).Id;

var changedByName = ((EntityReference)auditDetailsResponse.AudtiDetail.AuditRecord.Attributes["userid"]).Name;
```